# Set, get text and value in listitem view in Android

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have listview collection that show id and name in Android. I following example from [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) resource site.

But actually that example only display name. I wish similar like checkboxlist in ASP.NET that contain property text and value. So the text to show name and value store id. When user select one item, I could retrieve id by viewtext.

My question is how do I set id and name in same viewtext item? I wish could pass the id to another layout.

I know that possible using multi viewtext then set invisible of viewtext using map. How that could be waste memory.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest a custom listview. you can google for "custom listview" and will find a bunch of tutorials on that. simply said, it is a listview that has a custom row that you can specify in a xml file.

[here](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/07/14/fancy-listviews-part-one/) is a quite useful tutorial to start with.

here is what i coded, maybe it will help you. note that this is a bit different, because i am not defining a listactivity but a listview widget. but concerning the custom row item, it won't matter.

this will create a listview and specify an adapter for that listview.

```
    CustomListView listview = (CustomListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rowoflistview, R.id.label);
    listview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
```

my rowoflistview.xml looks like the following. it adds an image and a text to each row of the list. you can of course change it to (mostly) whatever you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rowselector"
>

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/musicicon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/musicicon"
    android:paddingLeft="3px"
/>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="26px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3px"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="false"
/>


</LinearLayout>
```

as i wanted the listview as a widget in my main activity and not as a fullscreen activity, i had to do it other than you when it comes to event listening and click listening. if you want it a bit easier, be sure to extend the listactivity in your custom listview-activity and override the default methods.

hope that was understandable to get a grip on the topic ;)

Answer (score 1):

Views have an associated tag Object map, which could contain your id http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29